# Geomesa Configuration Erorr

Tags: hadoop, geoserver, geomesa

I am using Hadoop 2.7 with geoserver 2.8.0, but while I am trying to configure Geomesa 1.2.0, I am getting this error message:

```
$ geomesa
Using GEOMESA_HOME = /usr/local/geomesa/dist/tools/geomesa-tools-1.2.0

Warning: you have not set ACCUMULO_HOME and/or HADOOP_HOME as environment variables.
GeoMesa tools will not run without the appropriate Accumulo and Hadoop jars in the tools classpath.
Please ensure that those jars are present in the classpath by running 'geomesa classpath' .
To take corrective action, please place the necessary jar files in the lib directory of geomesa-tools.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/core/client/TableNotFoundException
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.commands.TableConfCommand.<init>(TableConfCommand.scala:32)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.Runner$.createCommand(Runner.scala:50)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:21)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.TableNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The GeoMesa tools need Hadoop and Accumulo jars in order to connect to Accumulo.

One quick option is to run the GeoMesa tools from a tablet server or another machine already configured to be part of the Hadoop cluster.  If you are using another machine, you can mirror the `$HADOOP_HOME` and `$ACCUMULO_HOME` directories from a cluster node locally.

As another alternative, you can download the `install-hadoop-accumulo.sh` script in the `geomesa-tools/bin` directory to download a set of Hadoop and Accumulo jars.

Answer (score 0):

verify that corresponding jar file is present in the classpath, you can check this with the help of command:-   Geomesa classpath

If jar is not present then copy the jar in the Geomesa directoryin my case it is in following path:

/*/geomesa-1.2.4/dist/tools/geomesa-tools-1.2.4/lib/common/